# How to extract the output froman NLP model to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have trained an NLP Model (NER) and I have results in the below format:

```
for text, _ in TEST_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])

#Output
[('1131547', 'ID'), ('12/9/2019', 'Date'), ('USA', 'ShippingAddress')]
[('567456', 'ID'), ('Hills', 'ShippingAddress')]

#I need the output in the below format

ID       Date     ShippingAddress 
1131547 12/9/2019 USA     
567456    NA      Hills
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Probably figure out how to recast each list entry into a dictionary, and then just print the dictionary keys you want. Your question demonstrates no attempt, which will probably earn you downvotes and close votes; perhaps at least [edit] to show what you searched for and how those answers didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to import the data into a Pandas dataframe, you can use

```py
data_array = []

for text, _ in TEST_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    data_array.append({ent.label_:ent.text for ent in doc.ents})

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_array)
```

The test result:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_array)
        ID       Date ShippingAddress
0  1131547  12/9/2019             USA
1   567456        NaN           Hills
```